# How to write product of an array in vector-matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that, we have a vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}=[\beta_1,\ldots , \beta_n]$. Can we express $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i^2$ using vector/matrix operations on the vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$?

For e.g., we can write $\sum \beta^2_i= \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, $\sum \beta_i= \boldsymbol{\beta}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{1}$.

Comment: It is the square of a diagonal matrix that has $\beta_i$ as diagonal elements.

Comment: @EmilioNovati: You mean the determinant thereof?

Comment: Yes. It's substantially the same result as in the answer of AlexR = the determinat of the squared matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \beta_i^2 = \det(\beta \beta^T \odot I)$$
Where $\odot$ is the [hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I think, I should be a bit specific. I have the following relation between two vectors $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and $\boldsymbol{z}$ as follows, 
$\boldsymbol{\beta}=A\boldsymbol{z}+\boldsymbol{b}$, where $A$ is a matrix and  $\boldsymbol{b}$ is another vector.

If I have need $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i^2$ to be bigger than some $\delta$ then what kind of condition should be imposed on $\boldsymbol{z}$ ?